# "Unable to open the self-extracting executable file. The file is locked or in use by another process." error while installing anything on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

When I try to install adobe reader, or google chrome on my PC, I have this error coming: 
Unable to open the self-extracting executable file. The file is locked or in use by another process. The installation will terminate.

I searched google for answers, there were some people with similar problem, but apparently the only thing that helped was formatting hard drive )

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Try saving the installer to a folder you make on the C drive, save it there, then execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) and stop other programs which are using this software

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK, I will try.

Comment: That should also show which particular process (or file) is locking the said program. For example, if Unlocker lists "explorer.exe", it's possible the file/folder might be open in another window, etc.